# I installed node.js v 9.8.0 but i cant able to find node.js command prompt

Tags: node.js

I need node.js command prompt to execute my angular codes so i just installed node.js v9.8.0 (tried other versions too) its got installed successfully. But the issue is i cant able to find the node.js  command prompt.

windows 10 64 bit architecture

please provide me some way to get node.js command prompt

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are going to need to provide more details in order to get an answer. At least, which OS are you using? What do you mean by "node.js command prompt"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some help in writing good questions.

Answer (score 0):

In window search bar:

[image: search]

Just type---> node.js command prompt

[image: nodejs cmd]

After that press enter. And Below desired node.js command prompt open for you.
[image: cmd]